# How is Canada Vector Data (CanVec) hydrology data collected and updated?

Tags: remote-sensing, canada, data

Canada is vast and collecting any geographic data must be a monumental task. Natural Resources Canada provides a free access to a comprehensive Canada-wide topographic data now refereed to as CanVec (Canada Vector) data.  I often download and use CanVec datasets which are updated on yearly basis (current version 12 soon to be version 13) but I am curious how current thi data really is, namely hydrology.

How is this data captured and collected and how frequently are features such as waterbodies, wetlands updated?  I suspect image analysis using multispectral imagery but clearly some manual work is needed to enforce hydrological correctness. Is is even possible such data can be up to date?

Comment: Interesting question. When you download those files is there any metadata attached? I would even try contacting the dept and asking!

Comment: Why dont you ask to NRC [here](http://contact-contactez.nrcan-rncan.gc.ca/index.cfm?lang=eng&sid=7)

Comment: and the answer was?

Comment: Also, might be important to mention that CanVec is deprecated in favor of CanVec+

Answer (score 2):

The documentation (http://wmsmir.cits.rncan.gc.ca/index.html/pub/canvec/doc/CanVec_en_Specifications.pdf) states that:

> The static CanVec product is published at least once a year or when
>   data significant changes occur. Each new publication includes updates
>   gathered since the previous release.

and

> It originates from the best available data sources covering Canadian
>   territory, offers quality topographical information in vector format
>   and complies with international geomatics standards.

The updates occur when the providers provide new/updated information, or according to new work by NRCAN / CCMEO, which depends on governement policy/priorities.

There is a key note:

> Topographic features coming from the NTDB are not up to date. These
>   features are included in the CanVec product for cartographic reference
>   purpose only.

Comment: CanVec+ also sources existing datasets from the Provinces like in BC where the Fresh Water Atlas is a possible data source, which in turn gets some of its data from TRIM.